# Извлечении данные из база данных PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

```
package com.force.samples.entity;

import java.sql.*;


public class RetrieveData {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement prsment = null;
        ResultSet res = null;

        try {
            String usname = "devdbuser";
            String usPassword = "postgres";
            String host = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devdb";
            String drayver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
            Class.forName(drayver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, usname, usPassword);
            prsment = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users");
            res  = prsment.executeQuery();
            while (res.next()){
                System.out.print(res.getString(2) + "  ");
                System.out.print(res.getString(3) + "  ");
                System.out.print(res.getString(4) + "  ");
                System.out.print(res.getString(5) + "  ");
                System.out.print(res.getString(6) + "  ");
                System.out.print(res.getInt(7));

            }

           /* while (res.next()){
                int userID = res.getInt("userId");
                String userN = res.getString("userName");
                String userF = res.getString("userFam");
                String userLog = res.getString("userLogin");
                String userPsw = res.getString("userPass");
                String userPos = res.getString("userEmail");
                String userEm = res.getString("userEmail");
                int userVozrast = res.getInt("userAge");
                System.out.println(userID + " " + userN + " "+ userF + " " + userLog + " " + userPsw + " " + userPos + " " + userEm + " " + userVozrast);

            }*/

        } catch (Exception n) {
            System.out.println("Другая ошибка, проверьте свой код");
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Проверьте драйвера, правильно ли указали ");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось подключение к БД");
        }
        finally{ try{
            if (res!=null){
                res.close();
            }
            if (prsment!=null){
                prsment.close();
            }
            if (conn!=null){
                conn.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Razyedinenie ne udalos, ili Oshibka pri SQL zaprosa");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы проверить удалось ли подключение к БД я пробовал так и выводе получил ошибку что "Не удалось подключение к БД"

Вот мой stacktrace :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" не существует
  Позиция: 15
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AнbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at com.force.samples.entity.LGMAnaliz.main(LGMAnaliz.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: У меня установлена Intellij Idea 13.0. А этот симпл проект по SpringMVC JPA Hibernate. Настроил поме томкат и постгрес на существующую версию в компе. А java compiler и hibernate выделил одинаково и остальные. Объясните пожалюста из за какие ошибки может выйти такая ошибка?

Comment: Покажите stacktrace с ошибками. Без него ничего определенного сказать нельзя.

Comment: Я проверил в дибаге после выполнения запроса(res  = prsment.executeQuery(); ) идет на исключение catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось подключение к БД");
        }

Comment: Но у меня же есть таблица с таком именем, и я в pom.xmlе я заменил версия драйвера на свою установленную и его добавил списки библиотек... а какие еще мелочи тут...

Comment: А таблица с таким именем у вас действительно в базе devdb. Ощущение что либо не тот сервер либо не та база выбрана

Comment: Да уже все справлялось, просто название назвал с маленькими буквами и получилось, а я теперь знал что имя таблиц должны быть так

Comment: Спасибо вам за совет

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать имя схемы в строке JDBC-коннекта:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devdb?currentSchema=mySchema
```

где `mySchema` замените на имя схемы, в которой находится таблица `users`.
Ключевое слово `currentSchema` следует использовать в версиях Postgresql начиная с версии 9.4, а для более ранних версий применяйте searchpath:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devdb?searchpath=mySchema
```

Comment: Или в запросе пишите вместо просто users, users со схемой: SELECT * FROM mySchema.users